# How to programmatically fail scalatest from another thread

Tags: multithreading, scala, scalatest

As far as I know all assert methods throws exceptions that are handled by the test runner. I'm testing mutlithread application and would like to pass errors from spawned threads to the runner. I understand that runner could not interrupt threads, so I would shutdown them manually. But I would like to mark the test as failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mixin `ScalaFutures` trait from scalatest.

```
val f = Future.failed[Int](new RuntimeException)

whenReady(f.failed) { e =>
  assert(e.isInstanceOf[RuntimeException]
}
```

Comment: I'm testing my own futures. That would collide. For now I'm using checkpoints. They are threadsafe because they based on concurrent collection